# Pass By reference in golang

Tags: go, pass-by-reference

I have following code

```
package main

import "fmt"

type add struct{
    street string 
}

type user struct{
    age int
    address *add 
}

func change(name *add){
    name = &add{street:"street1"}
    fmt.Println(name.street)
}

func main(){

    user1 := &user{age: 22,address: &add{street:"street2"}}
    change(user1.address)
    fmt.Println(user1.address.street)
}
```

According to me it should give output

```
street1
street1
```

but it is showing

```
street1
street2
```

please anyone can explain why it is like this 
and how to achieve what i require

Thanks in advance

Comment: In `change()` you need to change the _pointed_ value: `*name = add{street: "street1"}`. Check your modified working code on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/-s-HATTl3k).

Comment: because name is a local variable changings its value won't effect the one defined in main()